# 3D cryptic featuring Mao, Stalin and Simba's uncle

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, three-dimensional

> [image]
>
> This is a three-dimensional cryptic crossword. The eleven squares above represent the layers of a $11\times11\times11$ cube.
>
> **Across**
> 21. Tribunal's way to imprison you in the old days (10)
> 25. Sir Isaac, among others, finishing solution of constant viscosity (9)
> 27. Refusing to take sides, armed forces left without a penny (4)
> 28. Aristocrat's farm building contains nothing (5)
> 30. River's little narrow segment (4)
> 31. Anxiety medication not completed by you in Germany's former capital (6)
> 33. Note: "Introduction to Art" catalogue is considered extremely accurately portrayed (9)
> 38. Templar Abe's quest protecting decorations (10)
> 41. Call back, get me a flower (5)
> 42. Valley revealed by galleon in an odd way (4)
> 43. Antelopes' shooters having change of heart? (4)
> 44. Specialist put in action outside Pakistan's capital (6)
> 46. Hungarian mother destroyed in gamma ray explosion (6)
> 48. No empty room is nothing out of the ordinary (4)
> 50. Messy, messy attic becomes orderly (10)
> 55. Tiny French town home to the Kent family (10)
> 59. Charge to indicate new testimony initially, including man with no left arm (10)
> 61. Federal union leaders with hands around central figures of Bastille escapees (9)
> 65. Extreme weather causes rain to ultimately wiggle around street (9)
> 68. Polish corporate leader abandoned, is bitter (4)
> 69. Instrument's transparent wrapping cut in half (5)
> 73. Hussein, Mao, Stalin ultimately reformed – not evil like Gandhi (10)
> 77. Soldier with strange stigma about extreme organ growth disorder (9)
> 80. Whistleblower mixed latte with prime liqueur in art gallery (10)
> 84. County office initially behind British Prime Minister (4)
> 85. Omitting the fifth in Phrygian – jazz bassist's disadvantage (5)
> 86. Sound detector is cut out (6)
> 89. Central to change: a starting point (4)
> 92. Rabbits move back and forth, followed by dogs (11)
> 95. *Fifty Shades* author leaves mongrel in short leash, results in the end being aromatic (10)
> 96. Drinks and stories with no end in sight (4)
> 98. Comfort partner with delicate fabric (6)
> 100. Almost enigmatic burial place (5)
> 103. Terrible, vile! (4)
> 104. King of creative arts (4)
> 105. Destroy uniform associated with revolutionary troop (6)
>
> **Down**
> 20. Office equipment platform south of Colorado (6)
> 21. African prisoner assembled legos before the end of parole (9)
> 22. Useless United Nations broke law all over the place (11)
> 23. Unusual solo to be around ten containers full of instruments (9)
> 24. No time to shock star (3)
> 29. Part of graph done poorly (4)
> 32. Evenly uniaxial metal object (4)
> 35. The Tamil Tigers, among others, are brutalized; ranks slain (3, 7)
> 36. The mind of an East Asian rapper and guerrilla leader (6)
> 37. Executed like an unsuccessful jury (4)
> 39. Pope's decree met with audible sighs, leading to hits (9)
> 40. Ageless type of inexpensive ship transport for cattle (5)
> 45. Bears are sorrowful, doze off looking up (6)
> 47. Stagger to celebration, disheartened (4)
> 49. Demolish Machu Picchu, for example (4)
> 52. Throw around money, finally travelling by air (6)
> 53. Oddly coloured pointer (4)
> 54. Unnaturally salted landforms (6)
> 56. Plainly show origin of official declaration (9)
> 57. Inspect a former soldier (3)
> 63. Request time coming before assignment (4)
> 64. Woman resorting to evil (6)
> 66. Creature in the middle of progress (4)
> 67. One of the Stooges entertaining extremely light sleeper (4)
> 71. Black gold rising above New England's symbol (4)
> 72. Followers of Squealer's ideology turned saints around Timbuktu's surroundings (10)
> 73. Strange thing attached to horse, causing horrible scenario (9)
> 74. Without unlimited motifs, debates leading to contradictions (9)
> 75. Regularly sleep in a string of flowers (3)
> 81. Large birds, including the rook? They live in the jungle (6)
> 82. Sensitive means of payment (6)
> 89. Naked predator called out (4)
> 90. Hold up some bananas – no lemon-like fruits (6)
> 91. Plant for upcoming virtual assistant (4)
> 93. Account books losing left and right margins (5)
> 94. Track revolutionary art west of Illinois (5)
> 97. It's a pest to see you breaking at sea (6)
> 99. Trousers backwards, video game hedgehog has top hat (6)
> 101. No explanatory introduction in long story (4)
> 102. So close, changing sides (4)
> 103. Nobleman's year living in hiding (4)
>
> **Away**
> 1. Simba's uncle – a comic book villain (10)
> 2. Elevator innovator known for sitting on the dock of the bay (4)
> 3. Opening umbrella after time of food (4)
> 4. Goddess is duplicated (4)
> 5. Primarily brownish-orange feline with stub tail! (6)
> 6. Perform vocals on the French record (6)
> 7. First sign of addiction: ignoring the odds – another stake put in the pot (4)
> 8. It's a circle during part of month! (4)
> 9. Heartless military forces are a personification of war itself (4)
> 10. Capture theatrical role, making comeback (4)
> 11. Briefly sorting out beginnings (6)
> 12. Reconstruction of arenas since Michelangelo's time (11)
> 13. Quiet apology about content missing in your study of ancient texts (10)
> 14. Special editions of newspapers as T-Rex rampaged (6)
> 15. Bizarrely nuanced noun, not communicated beforehand (11)
> 16. Repeat going around a river (4)
> 17. Retirees look around mansion, neglecting westernmost two rooms finally (10)
> 18. The final act is more intimate (6)
> 19. A key, perhaps to rent out property beyond the borders of Illinois (6)
> 22. Deranged aunt, at heart terrible, in possession of weapon (10)
> 25. Piece of any long fibre (5)
> 26. Properly noting reformed capital (10)
> 28. Gasping, heart-broken amid praise (10)
> 34. Picture of extremely impressive wizard (5)
> 51. Charge follows sick American – it's not what it seems (8)
> 57. D&G and others expressed opinions (6)
> 58. Novel inhabitants' introduction in the middle of irregular atoll (6)
> 60. Newspaper is secretly anti-Semitic? On the contrary! (5)
> 61. Some golf at a lakehouse resulting in death (5)
> 62. A billionaire's exits (5)
> 64. Taking third part of potion in bottles leads to signs of life (6)
> 67. Mossad's left wing has backing of US intelligence relating to laws in the Torah (6)
> 70. It's written right to left in absurd, unreadable characters (4)
> 76. The first in Noah's Ark is a spy (4)
> 77. Gloomy, rapacious boy missing (4)
> 78. Enlarge every second badger (3)
> 79. Country of nationalist rebels and heat (4)
> 83. Woman is fortunate losing one thousand (4)
> 85. Beverage for a friend (4)
> 87. Woman's dress is mostly toxic gas (4)
> 88. Essential to hearing! (3)

Comment: nice one +1! any excel version of grid available? thanks

Comment: Took ten minutes just to transcribe the grid - this is an impressively large puzzle!

Comment: Slowly working through this - 101D is a *very* nice clue!

Comment: What software did you use to generate and render the 3D grid?

Comment: @smci It's just an Excel sheet with some cells coloured. No actual 3D rendering involved :)

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle where you can fill out the riddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3wm9nhsL/

Comment: Ok but how did you store the 3D word structures? In your head?

Comment: @smci For the "away" clues I have one column on the side of the sheed with ready-made formulas that concatenate all letters from a certain row and column. That way when I type in letters I can see the resulting Z-axis words separately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The grid:**

> [image: filled 11×11 grid]

**Clue explanations:**

> [image: list of all clues with explanations]

Some comments on selected clues:

> **21A:** Great clue! Clever wordplay, and you managed to work in the archaism indication without compromising the smooth surface.
>  **49D:** Double defs using the same sense of the word for both definitions are generally frowned upon - they're *valid*, but often uninteresting. (Same with clues that decompose words in the "correct" ways, like SMALL+VILLE and a few others here.)
>  **67D:** Another fantastic clue - the "sleeper" double meaning was really clever!
>  **74D:** Was this supposed to be "unlimited motif"? It looks like there's an extra F that should get removed.
>  **97D:** I don't understand the word "to" here - it seems like it doesn't work in the cryptic reading (though I may be missing some parsing of it).
>  **101D:** This was also a really nice clue. The "long" misdirection was absolutely perfect.
>  **2W:** "Known for [...]" isn't a definition of OTIS (Redding) - he *is* known for Sittin' on the Dock of the Bay, but that's a descriptive phrase, not a definition - the parts of speech don't match up. ("Shines" or "is bright" don't define SUN.) Also, it seems like that title needs capitalization, but it's not there - removing necessary capitalization is generally forbidden, at least by the stricter clue standards (though adding *un*necessary capitalization is perfectly fine).
>  **88W:** Same problem as 2W -- "essential to hearing" is an adjective (well, adjectival phrase), but you're defining a noun. "Part that's essential to hearing" would be better.

Comment: got 79w, you're so quick, +1

Comment: 27A: (-s)POOR(-t)<. 84A: MAY+O_. 85A: MIN(-g)US. 74D: NEG(-oti)ATIONS [clue should read "motif", not "motifs", I think]. 79W: IRA+Q.

Comment: Everything's correct. Nice job!

Comment: Oof, looks like that part-of-speech issue gets me every time. In Finnish crosswords it's completely normal to have e.g. "Discovered America" as a clue for "Columbus", so it's really easy to miss those even though I *know* to look for them. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

### Partial, on mobile, unspoilered

**Across**
28 BAR O N
30 *LE NA*
41 L I LAC<
50 *SYSTEMATIC
103 &lit, *EVIL

**Down**
29 *NODE
32 _N_A_I_L
53 C_L_U_E_
54 *DELTAS
66 *ORGE*

**Away**
4 IS + IS
8 &lit, M O ON_
15 *UNANNOUNCED
78 _N_A_G
79 IRA + Q
88 &lit, *EAR*